# how do I make my ipad app pop up windows and making them close

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, mobile

I have a mobile app that is primarily external links.

Works GREAT in Android. Apple rejected it because the popups don't have "close" buttons.

I tried using this code to make that, but the windows open and hide instantly.

Need the script to make the windows open and have some kind of close button.

Help?

```
<a href="#" onclick="openInAppBrowserBlank('http://www.google.com');">NEW<br>new<br> InAppBrowser</a>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-x.x.x.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for device API libraries to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// device APIs are available
//

var ref = null;
function openInAppBrowserBlank(url)
{
    try {
        ref = window.open(encodeURI(url),'_blank','location=yes'); //encode is needed if you want to send a variable with your link if not you can use ref = window.open(url,'_blank','location=no');
        ref.addEventListener('loadstop', LoadStop);
        ref.addEventListener('exit', Close);
    }
    catch (err)    
    {
        alert(err);
    }
}
function LoadStop(event) {
     if(event.url == "http://www.mypage.com/closeInAppBrowser.html"){
        // alert("fun load stop runs");
         ref.close();
     }
}
function Close(event) {
     ref.removeEventListener('loadstop', LoadStop);
     ref.removeEventListener('exit', Close);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I don't see any code...

Comment: !a href="#" onclick="openInAppBrowserBlank('http://www.google.com');")NEW!br)new!br) InAppBrowser!/a)
 !script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-x.x.x.js")!/script)
    !script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8")


    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //



var ref = null;
function openInAppBrowserBlank(url)

Comment: try //
ref = window.open(encodeURI(url),'_blank','location=yes'); //encode is needed if you want to send a variable with your link if not you can use ref = window.open(url,'_blank','location=no');
         ref.addEventListener('loadstop', LoadStop);
         ref.addEventListener('exit', Close);
    ''
    catch (err)    
    //
        alert(err);
    ''
''
function LoadStop(event) //
         if(event.url == "http://www.mypage.com/closeInAppBrowser.html")//
            // alert("fun load stop runs");
             ref.close();

Comment: ''    
    ''
function Close(event) //
         ref.removeEventListener('loadstop', LoadStop);
         ref.removeEventListener('exit', Close);
    '' 
!/script)

Comment: Please put the code in your post.

Comment: sorry, I don't know how to post code

Comment: ok i did that.  Hope it works for you...I had alot of trouble getting it in there.

Comment: if there is better code to use (I am a newbie, using wordpress and apppresser, no real code skills).  Sorry for the misformed points.  Kinda stole from alot of Stackoverflow.

Comment: any help is much appreciated.  If I need to hire one of you for this (go easy on me, I'm upside down on this as it stands) I will.  Just need to deliver.

Comment: sorry. url for app is pwpllc.net/apppress3 on google store as Marion Il Official App

Comment: We are not here for hire. We are here to help programmers be better programmers. Did you mean to put `{` in for `//` and `}` in for `''`?

Comment: I actually had to replace all the { and } to get it to accept the code.

Comment: not trying to insult by offer to hire.  I'm simply at wit's end with this, and will do whatever to get over what (seems like it should be) a simple hurdle.

Comment: You should replace the `//`s and `''`s in your code. You should not have any trouble doing so.

Comment: I have tried. it keeps erroring out.  Sorry.

Comment: Can I email you the code or something?  I really just need guidance how to do it.

Comment: `code`

<a href="#" onclick="openInAppBrowserBlank('http://www.google.com');">NEW<br>new<br> InAppBrowser</a>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-x.x.x.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //



var ref = null;
function openInAppBrowserBlank(url)
{

Comment: try {
ref = window.open(encodeURI(url),'_blank','location=yes'); //encode is needed if you want to send a variable with your link if not you can use ref = window.open(url,'_blank','location=no');
         ref.addEventListener('loadstop', LoadStop);
         ref.addEventListener('exit', Close);
    }
    catch (err)    
    {
        alert(err);
    }
}

Comment: function LoadStop(event) {
         if(event.url == "http://www.mypage.com/closeInAppBrowser.html"){
            // alert("fun load stop runs");
             ref.close();
         }    
    }
function Close(event) {
         ref.removeEventListener('loadstop', LoadStop);
         ref.removeEventListener('exit', Close);
    } 
</script>